# how to compare lengths of two individual nodes in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

i have two for loops one is to print heading and the other loop is to print the corresponding values altogether in a tabular format.see the following code:

```
<fo:table>
            <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:for-each select="./list">
                     <xsl:if test="position()&lt;= 1">
                     <fo:table-row>
                                 <xsl:for-each select="./item">
                                 <xsl:if test="position() = 1 " >
                                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" width="auto">
                                 <fo:block color="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="11pt" font-weight="700" padding="5px"  space-before="5px" space-after="5px">&#160;<xsl:value-of select="val" />&#160;</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="position() = 2 or position() = 7 or position() = 12" >
                                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" width="auto">
                                    <fo:block color="#541f84" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="11pt" font-weight="700"  padding="5px" space-before="5px" space-after="5px"><xsl:value-of select="val" /></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                </xsl:if>
                                 <xsl:if test="position() = 3  or position() = 8 or position() = 13 or position() = 17" >
                                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" width="auto">
                                    <fo:block color="#bd5b10" font-family="5px" font-size="11pt" font-weight="700"  padding="5px" space-before="5px" space-after="5px"><xsl:value-of select="val" /></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                </xsl:if>
                                 <xsl:if test="position() = 4 or position() = 9 or position() = 14 or position() = 18" >
                                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" width="auto">
                                    <fo:block color="#147993" font-family="5px" font-size="11pt" font-weight="900"  padding="5px" space-before="5px" space-after="5px"><xsl:value-of select="val" /></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                </xsl:if>
                                 <xsl:if test="position() = 5 or position() = 10 or position() = 15 or position() = 19">
                                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" width="auto">
                                    <fo:block color="#38441a" font-family="5px" font-size="11pt"   font-weight="900" padding="5px" space-before="5px" space-after="5px"><xsl:value-of select="val" /></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                </xsl:if>
                                  <xsl:if test=" position() = 6 or position() = 11 or position() = 16" >
                                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" >
                                    <fo:block color="#656565" font-family="5px" font-size="11pt"   font-weight="900" padding="5px" space-before="5px" space-after="5px"><xsl:value-of select="val" /></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                </xsl:if> 
                                <xsl:if test="position() = last()" >
                                <xsl:variable name="count" select="position()" />
                                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" width="auto">
                                    <fo:block color="#38441a" font-family="5px" font-size="11pt"   font-weight="900" padding="5px" space-before="5px" space-after="5px"><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                         <xsl:for-each select="./list">
                         <xsl:if test="position()!=1">
                            <fo:table-row>
                                 <xsl:for-each select="./item">
                                <xsl:if test="position() = 1 or position() = 6 or position() = 11 or position() = 16">
                                <fo:table-cell border="1px" text-align="center" width="auto" background-color="#c0c0c0" border-color="#1d467b" border-width="1px" border-style="solid"  >
                                    <fo:block white-space-treatment="preserve" font-family="5px"   font-size="9pt"   >&#160;<xsl:value-of select="val" />&#160;</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="position()  = 2 or position() = 7 or position() = 12 or position() = 17">
                                <fo:table-cell border="1px"  text-align="center" width="auto" background-color="#b3a1c7" border-color="#1d467b" border-width="1px" border-style="solid"   >
                                    <fo:block font-family="5px" font-size="9pt" ><xsl:value-of select="val" /></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="position()  = 3 or position() = 8 or position() = 13">
                                <fo:table-cell border="1px"  text-align="center" width="auto" background-color="#fabf8f"  border-color="#1d467b" border-width="1px" border-style="solid"  >
                                    <fo:block  font-family="5px" font-size="9pt"   ><xsl:value-of select="val" /></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="position()  = 4 or position() = 9 or position() = 14">
                                <fo:table-cell border="1px"  text-align="center" width="auto"  background-color="#91cddb" border-color="#1d467b" border-width="1px" border-style="solid"   >
                                    <fo:block  font-family="5px"  font-size="9pt"   ><xsl:value-of select="val" /></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="position()  = 5 or position() = 10 or position() = 15">
                                <fo:table-cell border="1px"  text-align="center" width="auto" background-color="#c3d69b"  border-color="#1d467b" border-width="1px" border-style="solid"   >
                                    <fo:block  font-family="5px" font-size="9pt"    ><xsl:value-of select="val" /></fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
```

but here problem is some times in the first node the number of items coming from xsl is differ from the number of items in the rest of nodes.

now you can observe there is no tables cells appearing under v10 and v11,i know this happening because in the first node the no of items coming are 13 and for the rest of nodes no of items in each node are 11.. but any how even though the number of items differ from one node to another still i want table completely. like the number of columns should be equal to number of headings.

i thought to calculate number of iterations in first loop and then number of iterations in second loop and then by subtracting  them together and then thought to execute same table cell the rest of times but i couldn't do.

and the xml input is as follows:

```
<records>
<end-date>28-Jan-2014</end-date>
<month>January</month>
<list>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>Subject</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>V2</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>V2</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>V3</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>V3</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>V4</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>V5</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>V6</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>V7</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>V8</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>V9</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>V10</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>V11</val>
    </item>
</list>
<list>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>999870017</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item"/>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>01-Jan-2014 (6 Months after Day 1 +/- 4 Weeks)</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item"/>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item"/>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item"/>
</list>
<list>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>999870018</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item"/>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item"/>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item"/>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>01-Jan-2014 (6 Months after Day 1 +/- 4 Weeks)</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
</list>
<list>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>999870020</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>01-Jan-2014 (6 Months after Day 1 +/- 4 Weeks)</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item"/>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val> </val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="item">
        <val>01-Jan-2014 (36 Months after Day 1 +/- 4 Weeks)</val>
    </item>
</list>
<start-date>01-Jan-2014</start-date>
```

can any one help in this.
thanks

Comment: Your code is enormously repetitive. If you find yourself copy-and-pasting the same line of code *even once*, you are already doing it wrong. You've copy-pasted everything *five times*. I think this should not be fixed, but rewritten entirely. Also, please include the XML you are working with.

Comment: i am very new to this xsl so i made as per my knowledge the reason why i wrote code 5times in the two loops is to apply five different colors,,, if you can still optimize it please tell me how...and first of all can you please solve the issue mentioned in the question primarily.

Comment: *"the reason why i wrote code 5times in the two loops is to apply five different colors,,,"* You should ask a separate question about that. Make sure to read about `<xsl:attribute-set>` before that.

Comment: thats not my issue now..and even i am not asking solution for that 5different colors of 5different columns consecutively..now the only question is how to bring the two more empty columns under v10 and v11 to bring a complete look for my table.i cant statically define them because in this xml its like this,but for some other xml it may miss 3 or 4 more columns cant be predicted. so i thought to calculate no of loops on the 1st loop to say count1 and no of loops in the 2nd for each loop to count 1 and now count 1- count 2!=0, then i thought to execute the empty table cells (count1-count2)times.

Answer (score 2):

> the number of columns should be equal to number of headings.

A simple solution is to iterate over the items in the heading list and create a cell for each - regardless of the list you are processing. Then get the value from the corresponding item in the current list - if it exists. Here is a simplified example, creating an HTML table:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="records/list[1]/item">
                <th><xsl:value-of select="val" /></th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody> 
        <xsl:for-each select="records/list[position()&gt;1]">
            <xsl:variable name="row" select="position()+1" />
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="../list[1]/item">
                <xsl:variable name="col" select="position()" />
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="../../list[$row]/item[$col]/val" /></td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tbody>    
</table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: here my xsl code for generating pdf but i think your code suites when we want output in html,,, and also i need to apply 5 different colors for each 5 consecutive columns and vise versa... so your code not achieving my colors condition and not fit for pdf generation. can you please edit my code and achieve solution.

Comment: @preeth This answer shows you one solution to your question ("How to output as many cells as in the first row?"). It's not wrong just because you can't copy and paste it. You can use this method, if you try a little.

Comment: in your code your trying to out value as select="../../list[$row]/item[$col]/val" but how this bring two more columns when there are only 11 values in each <list></list> except 1st list.when there exist a value then only it can bring cell and put some value into that.

Comment: @preeth The code is only an illustration to the principle stated in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: but can you please provide code as per my requirement and in xsl fo for pdf table not for html

Comment: @preeth No, of course not. That's your job, not mine. I was only trying to help you understand how this problem can be solved. I don't work here.

Comment: ok thank you. but atleast can you tell me how to declare a integer variable in xsl and how to increment its value in every for loop iteration and then later how to make use of this integer variable in xsl if condition

Comment: @preeth That would be a completely different approach. I have posted another answer to show how that could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach, using an iterator to count up to the number of items in the first list:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<table>
    <xsl:variable name="columns" select="count(records/list[1]/item)" />
    <xsl:for-each select="records/list">
        <tr>    
            <xsl:call-template name="create-cells">
                <xsl:with-param name="columns" select="$columns"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </tr>   
     </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="create-cells">
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="columns"/> 
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $columns">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="item[$i]/val" /></td>
        <xsl:call-template name="create-cells">
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="columns" select="$columns"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```