# Get XSLT to place XML data in correct columns

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I was wondering if an xslt guru could me solve this problem.

I have the following XML:

```
<profile>
    <list xid="data.table">
        <data-detail-value>
            <name>Name</name>
            <dbid>1</dbid>
            <value>Tim</value>
        </data-detail-value>
        <data-detail-value>
            <name>Area</name>
            <dbid>3</dbid>
            <value>New York</value>
        </data-detail-value>
        <data-detail-value>
            <name>Business</name>
            <dbid>6</dbid>
            <value>Drex Technology</value>
        </data-detail-value>
        <data-detail-value>
            <name>Ethnicity</name>
            <dbid>8</dbid>
            <value>Spanish</value>
        </data-detail-value>
    </list>
    <list xid="data.table">
        <data-detail-value>
            <name>Name</name>
            <dbid>1</dbid>
            <value>Bethany</value>
        </data-detail-value>
        <data-detail-value>
            <name>Tasks</name>
            <dbid>7</dbid>
            <value>Regulation</value>
        </data-detail-value>
        <data-detail-value>
            <name>Position</name>
            <dbid>2</dbid>
            <value>Owner</value>
        </data-detail-value>
    </list>
</profile>


<list xid="data.table.head">
  <head-value>
    <name>Area<name>
    <dbid>3</dbid>
  </head-value>
  <head-value>
    <name>Name<name>
    <dbid>1</dbid>
  </head-value>
  <head-value>
    <name>Business<name>
    <dbid>6</dbid>
  </head-value>
  <head-value>
    <name>Tasks<name>
    <dbid>7</dbid>
  </head-value>
  <head-value>
    <name>Ethnicity<name>
    <dbid>8</dbid>
  </head-value>
  <head-value>
    <name>Position<name>
    <dbid>2</dbid>
  </head-value>
</list>
```

I'm trying to convert this to an excel document. The trouble I am having is that certain data does not always exist for every list. So the columns do not match up appropriately.

I have the following XSLT I'm using to get the table column headers

```
<xsl:for-each select="list[@xid = 'data.table.head']/head-value">
<xsl:sort select="dbid" data-type="number" /><xsl:value-of select="name"/>,
<xsl:text/></xsl:for-each>
```

This outputs all of the values of the table header columns like and orders them by dbid

Name | Position | Area | Business | Tasks | Ethnicity

Next part is where I'm stumped. How do I get the data from the list xid data.table to list those values out in the corresponding columns like so,

```
Name     | Position | Area     | Business        | Tasks       |  Ethnicity

Tim                   New York   Drex Technology                  Spanish
Bethany    Owner                                   Regulations
```

I'm able to get it to work when all the values are present but when some data is not available in the XML, I run into issues. I.e. "New York" appears under "Position."

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: How would you do it in another language? It's the same string-processing problem; if you're working with fixed column text, it's your responsibility to calculate and append appropriate padding. Or, more typically, you could generate an HTML or XSL-FO table and let the next stage downstream deal with that rendering.

Comment: "*I'm trying to convert this to an excel document.*" It doesn't look that way. Are you perhaps trying to generate a .csv file to be **imported** by Excel? In addition: your XML input lacks a root element.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, here is a very similar question to yours - with two alternative answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348003/how-to-compare-lengths-of-two-individual-nodes-in-xsl

Answer (score 0):

with this XSLT,

```
<xsl:stylesheet  version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="header" select="root/list[@xid='data.table.head']"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="list[@xid = 'data.table.head']"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="profile"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="profile">
    <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tbody>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="list[@xid = 'data.table.head']">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="descendant::head-value">
                    <xsl:sort select="dbid" data-type="number" />
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="profile/list[@xid = 'data.table']">
        <xsl:variable name="cell_data" select="descendant::data-detail-value"/>
        <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="$header/head-value">
            <xsl:sort select="dbid" data-type="number" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current()/dbid=$cell_data/dbid">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="$cell_data/value[preceding-sibling::dbid=current()/dbid]"/></td>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <td/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied with with this input:

it outputs

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Position</td>
            <td>Area</td>
            <td>Business</td>
            <td>Tasks</td>
            <td>Ethnicity</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tim</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>Drex Technology</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Spanish</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bethany</td>
            <td>Owner</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Regulation</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

maybe you can adapt this approach to your current problem.

Comment: This works except the db-id's will constantly change. How would account for that? Could I do some sort of for-each loop to iterate over all the db-id values? Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my answer. If this is acceptable, please click on the check mark on the left (just below the arrowheads).

Comment: have you tested the code above already? have you got any feedback?